# How to pass additional value to controller when it's not in the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have my models

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Photo
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }
}

public class PhotoAttach
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }

    public virtual Photo Photo { get; set; }

    public bool IsThumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

In my `CreatePost` view, I want user to be able to select some existing photos to be attached to creating post. I made this using some scripts, so when user clicks submit button I already have a JSON object containing all photos ids that are going to be attached.

But this view uses `Post` as the model. So how can I refer to this object from controller?

I though about converting it to a string and adding some hidden input. But is it possible to access this from the controller?

Is there any way to do that without creating new view model?

Comment: The model used when rendering the view has nothing to do with the model used as input to a controller action.  They can be different models.

Comment: You can add  list<int>photoIds as an extra parameter to the CreatePost View. Public class CreatePost(Post post, list<int> photoIds){ ... code here }

Comment: @HastaPasta but then how to pass that parameter from the view when submitting form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. 
your action result be like this

```
 public ActionResult AddProductToCart_Details(Post post, FormCollection form)
```

You can save value in hidden name in html.

```
<input id="formCheck" type="checkbox" name="xxxx" />
```

And get that value like this.

```
var day = form["XXXX"];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to create a new viewmodel, you can add a new parameter to your HttpPost action method to accept the collection of file ids.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePost(Post model,IEnumerable<int> fileIds)
{
    // you can loop through fileIds colleciton
    return Json(new { status="success"});
}
```

Assuming your ajax code to send the data is including the `fileIds` property which is an array of your file id's.

```
$(function () {

    $("yourFormId").submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var fileIdsToSend= [345, 56, 234]; //Array of Id's you want to send 
        var _f = $(this);
        var data = {
            Title: $("#Title").val(),
            Description :$("#Description").val(),
            fileIds: fileIdsToSend
        };

        $.post(_f.attr("action"),data, function (response) {
           // do something with the response
        });

    });             

});
```

The Ideal solution would be to use a view model specific to your view and not use the entity models as view models.

```
public class CreatePostVm
{
  public string Title {set;get;}
  public string Description {set;get;}
  public IEnumerable<int> FileIds {set;get;}
}
```

And your HttpPost action would be accepting an object of this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePost(CreatePostVm model)
{
  // do something and return something
}
```

The above jquery code will work for sending data to this version of action method as well.

Comment: Is it possible without using ajax and view model?

Comment: It is, Keep the form field name same as the property name.(FileIds). But i would suggest going through the view model route.

Answer (score 1):

```
var PhootoIdList = GetAllYourPhotoIds;
var PostModel = {
    Title : GetTitle,
    Description : GetDescription
};
$.ajax({
    url: '/mycontroller/action',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        photoIds: PhotoIdList,
        model: {
            Post: PostModel
        }
    }),
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Without Ajax

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Posts", FormMethod.Post, null) )
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Post</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <select name="photoIds" id="photoIds" multiple>
            <option value="AAAA">Photo 1</option>
            <option value="BBBB">Photo 2</option>
            <option value="CCCC">Photo 3</option>
        </select>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Title,Description")] Post post, string[] photoIds)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Posts.Add(post);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(post);
        }
```

Comment: Is it possible without using ajax?

Comment: @using(Html.BeginForm("action", "controller",
                       new { PhotoIds = "GetPhotoIdsHere" }, FormMethod.Post, null)